# React final form - infinite submitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

If we try to send this form several times, we will get **infinite submitting**.

If we set the **sleep()** function on **onSubmit**, everything works fine.

Why? How to do it right?

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Form, Field } from 'react-final-form'

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const onSubmit = async values => {
  // Everything works fine with sleep()
  // await sleep(100);
  console.log('onSubmit...');
}

const App = () => (
    <Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      render={({ handleSubmit, submitting }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field name="notes" component="textarea" placeholder="Notes" />
          <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      )}
    />
)

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly you want to do? Are you trying to send this form, how many times?

Comment: I just want to display console.log() as many times as I clicked the submit button. I want to understand why final-form does not work properly

Answer (score 0):

To handle submit synchronously like what are doing, return `undefined` ie:

```
const onSubmit = values => {
  console.log('onSubmit...');
  return;
}
```

See https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/Config#onsubmit

Comment: Unfortunately, I need an asynchronous function

Comment: if you want async, then return a promise that resolves to `console.log`, have you tried that?

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question :), are you asking why you need `await sleep(100)` before `console.log`? `await` is how you resolve promise if you need async function.